# 5volt Arduino Pro Mini Not Able to Drive 5 Volt actuator But The same work perfectly Done by Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to drive an actuator from 5 volt Arduino pro mini and it's control by Bluetooth signal from mobile .

circuit detail:

1)Arduino Promini 5 volt
2) Hc05 Bluetooth Module 
3)5volt Actuator
I was powering 11.8 Volt directly to the RAW pin of  Arduino pro mini .

When It was receiving 1 or 0 it is unable to control the actuator and after connecting the data pin of actuator with pin 13 of arduino pro-mini the flash light continuously blinking

But Above same operation perfectly done by Arduino Uno Board. So is there any possible to control the actuator using arduino promini over bluetooth signal. Reason behind I am using Arduino pro mini instead of Arduino Uno it's took less space.

Arduino Code:

```
            #include<SoftwareSerial.h>

            SoftwareSerial BT(2, 3); 

            #include <Servo.h>

            Servo myservo;

            int ServoPin =13; 

            void setup()  
            {  
              Serial.begin(9600);
              myservo.attach(ServoPin);
              pinMode(ServoPin, OUTPUT);
              digitalWrite(ServoPin, LOW);
              myservo.write(40);

              // set digital pin to control as an output
              pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
             // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
             BT.begin(9600);
            // Send test message to other device
            BT.println("Hello from Arduino");
            }
            char a; // stores incoming character from other device
            void loop() 
           {
             if (BT.available())// if text arrived in from BT serial...  

                {
                      a=(BT.read());
                       Serial.println(a);
                          if (a=='1')

                             { 
                           digitalWrite(9, HIGH); 
                           BT.println(" You have to turn oN the LED/servo| I got the command : 1 ")  ; 



                           Serial.println("I got the command :");



                           Serial .println(a);
                           myservo.write(180); 

                              a=' '; 
                               }
                           else if (a=='0')
                           {
                                myservo.write(40);

                                digitalWrite(9, LOW);

                                BT.println(" You have to turn Off the LED!/servo| I got the command :0");

                               Serial.println("I got the command :");

                               Serial .println(a);


                                          a=' ';
                                      }


                        }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is with the current. first check how much power is required to drive the actuator. if the current is insufficient you can use ULN2003 it's a relay driver ic but you can use it for your ckt if you are less in space you can use single darlington pair.

Comment: other than actuator remaining things are working properly or they are also giving improper result??? and can you share the readings(V  I) of pin 9